# Make Android File

Tags: ros, gradle, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instructions on the website:http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html, but an error occored at step 3 :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open task artifact state cache (/opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/.gradle/1.0-milestone-8a/taskArtifacts).

> java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

there are so many guides on the topic- how to create ros android. I tried almost every method, but failed. Is it possible that someone make a step-by-step guide so i can learn form it? thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29803/make-android-file/) by [hanbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1967/hanbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're looking at the correct documentation. However, I imagine you do not have permission to build from source out of your /opt directory.

If you're building from source, you probably want to do so from an overlay. There is an example of this here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/SetupEnvironment

I'll update the rosjava documentation to include that step.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0